# change between two events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/skV74/

so i need to be able to draw circles and straight lines connecting each circle with each other, so i made 2 buttons one to draw circles and other to draw lines.

but it doesn't work, it doesn't able to switch between circle and line!, i believe that i made stupid mistake :D.

and another part of code i don't get it

```
var offset = $(this).offset();// return he coordinates 
        var x = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var y = e.pageY - offset.top;
```

why using offest here? and what does it do?

finally im doing a visualization of dijkstra shortest path algorithm so if there any suggestion or additional help you can give, or any advise .. i need it :)

thanks in advance

Comment: The `offset` code grabs the position of the cursor on the screen.

Comment: so why subtracting here ? e.pageX - offset.left;

Comment: because it takes into account the page's scroll position

Answer (score 1):

First, you were never unbinding the event handlers:

```
$('#myCanvas').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
```

Second, there's no reason to put a DOM ready handler inside the functions you have.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8bF4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind your click events before you add a new one. So, replace each one of these lines:

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click',function(e)
```

with this:

```
$('#myCanvas').off('click').on('click', function(e)
```